# Is there an index that will speed up a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this CTE which takes about two seconds to complete.

Is there an index I can add that will speed it up?

```
with item_cte
as
(select Id, itemTypeId from Items where Id = 230
        and entityStatusId = 1
     union all
     Select i.id, i.itemTypeId from items I
     inner join item_CTE icte on icte.Id = i.ParentId where i.entityStatusId = 1
)
Select ItemTypeId, Count(*) as ItemCount from item_cte group by ItemTypeId option(MaxRecursion 100)
```

Comment: When you a run a query which has one or more CTE in it, SQL Server will just inline the CTE code.  So, to speed up a query inside a CTE, you need to do the same things you would to do the raw SQL code by itself.

Comment: If you need to speed up a hierarchical query, consider switching to using `hierarchyid` to model it instead of the parent/child model. Parent/child *has* to result in multiple levels of lookups. (Of course, this shouldn't be done blindly; you need to consider all query patterns and *measure* whether it'll be an overall benefit to make such a switch)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's very interesting about the `hierarchyid` At some point, I will have to get up to speed on that, as it looks like it is much faster than using parent/child with CTE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed this query you could consider such indexes:

1. Oboviously index (clustered) on `Items.Id`, which probably you already have.
2. Also (non-clustered) index on `Items.entityStatusId`.
3. Similairly, clustered index on `item_CTE.id`, which also, I guess, you have.

Comment: Is it valid to rewrite a recursive CTE like that? So far as I'm aware, you need anchor and non-anchor queries and they *have* to be combined by `UNION ALL`s.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  But when I run the above, I get the error message: `Recursive common table expression 'item_cte' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I didn't realize it's recursive!

Comment: @Greg0 I didn't realize it's recursive.. :) But remarks on indexes are still valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the table itself, it's usage, and the existing indexes, it's difficult to make concrete recommendations. However, some things to consider...

- Non-clustered index on entityStatusId is the obvious one. Assuming that's in place, look at the query plan. You'll likely see a Key Lookup. Consider adding the itemTypeId as an included column which should prevent the key lookup (this is known as a covering index).
- Depending on the size of the table, and how selective the entityStatusId is, you could consider the use of a filtered index on entityStatusId.

As Damien suggested, you could look at using hierarchyid and performing some tests to prove if this is faster. However, that assumes you are able to modify the underlying schema.

Feel free to post your query plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/